# creating a table from a text file

Tags: c#, string, trim

i want to create a table in my c# application from a text file. In the text file it says 
1:"Transmitter", 1, grid, 32,6. This means that the name of the table is Transmitter, it belongs to tab number 1, it is a grid type, it has 32 rows and 6 columns.

can anybody help?

this is my code-----

```
String line;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            getFormContentFromFile();

        }

        public void getFormContentFromFile()
        {
            using (StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader("neo2G.res"))
            {
                while (!Reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    line = Reader.ReadLine();

                    if (line.Equals("TABS"))
                    {
                       while (!line.Equals(".."))
                        {
                            line = Reader.ReadLine();
                            if (!line.Equals(".."))
                            {
                                line = Regex.Replace(line, @"[\d-]", string.Empty);
                                line = line.Trim(':', '"');

                                TabPage myTabPage = new TabPage(line);
                                tabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);
                            }
                            }
                    }

                    if(line.Equals("TABLES"))
                    {



                    }
                }
```

Comment: Split the data you read from the file by comma and then interpret the split-array so it suits your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good article on reading in CSV files:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/415732/Reading-and-Writing-CSV-Files-in-Csharp

I would recommend performing Split to parse your data:

```
string stringIreadIn = //...
string[] myData = stringIreadIn.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());
```

What kind of table do you want to create?  You can create tables in C# using ADO.NET:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/361579/A-Beginners-Tutorial-for-Understanding-ADO-NET

Here is how you could create a DataTable:

```
        DataTable table = new DataTable(); 
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) 
        { 
            table.Columns.Add("My column " + i.ToString(), Type.String);
        }   
        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) 
        {
            DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
            // populate data row with values here
            table.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the info. i want to create a grid table with 32 rowvs and 6 columns

Comment: Actually, if you are wanting to create structured tables, I would recommend using XML: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9494/Manipulate-XML-data-with-XPath-and-XmlDocument-C

Comment: thank you for the help, do you know how to thos row numbers to?

Comment: Sorry, the question you asked is not clear.  What exactly do you need to know?